# Access linux fc4 graphical mode from windows pc

Tags: linux

I have a Linux server fedora core 4 .Now I want to remotely access the graphical mode of that Linux server from my local windows pc. How can I do that?
[ Pls suggest me except freenx, vnc server]. 
Pls help me to do it easily.

Thanks in advance
riad

Comment: Don't you think it's time to upgrade? FC4 has been out of support for 4 years. Fedora 11 is free.

Answer (score 2):

I like [Xming](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/). It's an X Window Server that runs on Microsoft Windows.

Comment: This combined with putty X11 forwarding over SSH is an excellent solution, and one that doesn't cause my servers to waste time running a GUI

Answer (score 0):

Run a VNC server on your Fedora box, and connect using TightVNC from your windows box.  Or, you can use a remote desktop server on Fedora, and connect from a Windows Remote Desktop client.